# Out of memory issue in jdk but works fine in openjdk, java application deployed on jboss 5.1

Tags: jboss5.x, java-6

I have deployed my java application on jboss and linux 2.6.32 .
The machine has 8 gb of memory, but when I run the application on openjdk using

> JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -server -Xms2048m -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=700m
>   -XX:NewRatio=3 -XX:+DisableExplicitGC     -XX:+UseParallelOldGC -XX:ParallelGCThreads=4     -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000     -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Dofbiz.home=adasdfasdf".

It's working fine.
But when i try to run the same on jdk 1.6 its giving me out of memory error as below:

```
There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 444 bytes for vframeArray::allocate
# Possible reasons:
#   The system is out of physical RAM or swap space
#   In 32 bit mode, the process size limit was hit
# Possible solutions:
#   Reduce memory load on the system
#   Increase physical memory or swap space
#   Check if swap backing store is full
#   Use 64 bit Java on a 64 bit OS
#   Decrease Java heap size (-Xmx/-Xms)
#   Decrease number of Java threads
#   Decrease Java thread stack sizes (-Xss)
#   Set larger code cache with -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=
# This output file may be truncated or incomplete.
#
#  Out of Memory Error (allocation.inline.hpp:44), pid=11749,     tid=707259248
#
# JRE version: 6.0_32-b05
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (20.7-b02 mixed mode linux-x86 )

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x2a5b5000):  JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_Java,     id=11768, stack(0x2a22e000,0x2a27f000)]

 Stack: [0x2a22e000,0x2a27f000],  sp=0x2a27cd50,  free space=315k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
 V  [libjvm.so+0x7257e0]
```

How can i make the application run using jdk 1.6?

Comment: You are using the 32bit version of the JDK. Try with a 64 bits version. The error message is very clear about your solutions.

Comment: Thanks Guillaume for your rapid guidance. Yea after upgrading to 64 bits, i m able to increase the memory